# Css grids auto span available space

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create a css grid based layout with 2 items, first item will span 1/3 of the width and the second will span 2/3 of the width but when the width get below a certain threshold the second item will jump down to the second row and the first item should fill the first row.

```
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.span1 {
  background-color:green;
}

.span2 { 
  background-color:red;
  grid-column-end: span 2; 
}
```

I have an example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qopvQz

Everything works fine but I want the first item (green) to auto expand to the full width when the second item (red) jumps down to the second row. As of now the first item will only fill half of the first row. Is this possible to achieve with css grids (or flexbox)?

Comment: What you are describing is not a *grid*. flexbox and a media query would seem ideal

Comment: Could this be achieved with flexbox without media queries?

Comment: That could actually work, ill try it out, thank you.

Comment: Since you've set `span2` to `grid-column-end: span 2`, it takes up two columns. `span1` covers only one column. This remains true after wrapping. So `span1` will always be shorter than `span2`. A simple media query can solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that but it does require some hard-coded min-widths or `flex-shrink` set to `0`.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.flex.narrow {
  width: 250px;
}

.span1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  /* min-width: 100px; */
}

.span2 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 2 0 200px;
   /* min-width: 200px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <div class="span1">A</div>
  <div class="span2">B</div>

</div>

<div class="flex narrow">

  <div class="span1">A</div>
  <div class="span2">B</div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you want to simplify the `min-width` and `flex` rules, just use `flex: 1 0 100px` / `flex: 2 0 200px`. That sets the item to a minimum width and allows it to grow.

Comment: Thanks...obvious really but i was in a rush :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flex instead of grids for this purpose.
Pay attention to `flex-grow` ability. Check more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp) 
In result you'll get something like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMyoew

Answer (score 0):

You can try container query

```css
body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .grid {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
                grid-template-rows: auto;
                grid-auto-flow: dense;
                gap: 20px;
                padding: 20px;
                container: test / inline-size;
            }

            .cell {
                padding: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                grid-column: span 1;
                background: red;
            }

            .w-2 {
                grid-column: span 2;
                background: blue;
            }

            .w-3 {
                grid-column: span 3;
                background: green;
            }

            /* 750px + 2 * gap */
            @container test (inline-size < calc(750px + 2 * 20px)) {
                .w-3 {
                    grid-column: span 2;
                }
            }

            /* 500px + gap */
            @container test (inline-size < calc(500px + 20px)) {
                .w-2, .w-3 {
                    grid-column: span 1;
                }
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="cell">1</div>
            <div class="cell">2</div>
            <div class="cell">3</div>
            <div class="cell w-2">4</div>
            <div class="cell w-3">5</div>
            <div class="cell">6</div>
            <div class="cell">7</div>
            <div class="cell">8</div>
            <div class="cell">9</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```